# SONAR asking to Make "UserProfile" serializable or don't store it in the session

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have the following piece of code in my program and I am running SonarQube 5 for code quality check on it after integrating it with Maven.

However, Sonar is asking to Make "UserProfile" serializable or don't store it in the session.

Why?

```
private void setUserProfileinSession(HttpServletRequest request,
        Authentication authentication) {

    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(
            authentication.getAuthorities());
    GrantedAuthority authority = authorities.get(0);
    UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile();
    userProfile.setUserName(authentication.getName());
    userProfile.setUserRole(authority.getAuthority());
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute(EnumGlobal.USERPROFILE.getName(), userProfile);
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.info("JK SSO Role Set in Session by AuthenticationSuccessHandler:"
                + userProfile.getUserRole());
    }
```

> Facing problem in line 10 -- (EnumGlobal.USERPROFILE.getName(), userProfile)

```
public class UserProfile extends BaseBO {

String userName;
String userRole;

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getUserRole() {
    return userRole;
}

public void setUserRole(String userRole) {
    this.userRole = userRole;
}
```

Comment: *How to remove this error?*, you make it serializable or don't store it in the session. That is pretty clear don't you think?

Comment: FYI sonar has explanations for its advice built into it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web containers may need to serialize session content. One example is to transfer sessions to another physical machine when you run several instances of the container.

For this reason, all objects put into a session should be serializable (i.e. implement the interface `java.io.Serializable`).

The error message gives already hints how to remove the error: either make the object serializable or don't store it in the session.